# Get the source.unsplash url of the picture

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a website where I load this link (https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080/?wallpaper,landscape) to get a random photo. The photo behind the link changes periodically and when its loaded of the site I only see this link https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080/?wallpaper,landscape do you think there is a way to get the real source like this: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1458571037713-913d8b481dc6?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1080&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjF9&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1920". When I open up the chrome devtools I can see the source in the Application tab but how can i access them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use axios library to fetch the image and get the response url :

```js
let randomURL = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080/?wallpaper,landscape';

axios.get(randomURL).then( data => {
  // the url of the random img
  console.log(data.request.responseURL);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha256-S1J4GVHHDMiirir9qsXWc8ZWw74PHHafpsHp5PXtjTs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and with vanilla JS :

```js
fetch("https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080/?wallpaper,landscape").then( data => {
 console.log(data.url);                
});
```

and if you want to support old browsers :

```js
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080/?wallpaper,landscape", true);
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (request.readyState === 4) {
  if (request.status === 200) {
   console.log(request.responseURL);
  }
 }
}
```